# How to set file timestamp to timestamp from within file, for MP4 and JPEG?

Tags: file-attributes, attributes

I have many pictures which I take from my windows phone. When I copy the pictures onto my hard drive, it changes all the dates "created" to the date they were "copied" over. However the date created remains the same on the file.

How can I automatically change the attributes for "date created" to what the "date modified" or "date taken" was, and the other way around?

This is about a date recorded attribute in windows 8 (I used to be able to see this in windows 7).

I would need to do this for both MP4 & JPEGs.

Comment: Hi Jay. Product recommendation questions are off-topic on SuperUser, and this question is at risk of being closed as asking for product recommendations, so I have edited your question to ask how to solve what I believe is your problem instead. Should you feel my edit changed the intent of your question in any way, feel free to **[edit]** further.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with

```
ExifTool "-DateTimeOriginal>FileCreateDate" name.jpg
```

but only on windows, it seems linux doesn't provide a way to change the file create date (according to a comment by the developer of ExifTool).

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to use MP4Workshop. It is a new software designed to edit the internal metadata of the MP4, MOV and JPG files. It is free software, you can download from mp4workshop.com.

It can handle single files, but in essence it is aimed at batches of files (mp4,mov and jpg), which is usually the case when you camera setting is wrong..

Important: the software adds timezone offset! Many mp4/mov files only contain a timestamp in the mvhd atom, and this is only UTC time. Files from Apple devices usually contain the Quicktime tag/key ‘com.apple.quicktime.creationdate’ and this seems to be the only key that is widely used by many softwares (like GooglePhotos) to read the time including offset (e.g. 2021-03-04 12:18:02+01:00). When not present, MP4Workshop adds this key to your video file so it can store the time correctly, including the offset. For jpg files it adds Exif GPSTime (UTC) and local time.

It is free, GUI based, does NOT re-encode you video and has a preview window for the file you're working on. There is a tutorial on the website, and it has built-in tutorial hints for first-time use.
See [mp4workshop.com](https://mp4workshop.com)

Greetings, John

Here is a screenshot (in this case including the tutorial call-outs). P.S.: The software can do much more like: adding GPS location coordinates, edit other metadata, view the atom structure of a file.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWFW2.jpg)